# How to add a second datalabel to ChartJs bar charts?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart as below, it has a datalabel inside each stacked bar showing a percentage. Now I am wanting to add a second set of datalabel on top of each bar(consider each set of stacked bar as one bar) that shows the month, say for person 1, the right bar says current month(may), the middle one says last month(april), the left bar says march.

I only need three month.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
const trend_options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: function(value, ctx) {
        const otherDatasetIndex = ctx.datasetIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        const total = ctx.chart.data.datasets[otherDatasetIndex].data[ctx.dataIndex] + value;
        return `${(value / total * 100).toFixed()}%`;
      },

      font: {
        weight: "bold"
      },
      color: "#fff",
      display: function(context) {
        let index = context.dataIndex;
        let value = context.dataset.data[index];
        return value > 0; // display labels with a value greater than 0
      }
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
      suggestedMax: 15,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 5,
      }
    }
  },
};


const app_data_trend = [{
    label: 'App Month 1 TW',
    data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4],
    backgroundColor: '#007bff',
    stack: 'Stack 0',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 1 jira',
    data: [3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3],
    backgroundColor: '#6DB526',
    stack: 'Stack 0',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 2 TW',
    data: [4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4],
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    stack: 'Stack 1',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 2 jira',
    data: [4, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    stack: 'Stack 1',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 3 TW',
    data: [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3],
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    stack: 'Stack 2',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 3 jira',
    data: [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5],
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    stack: 'Stack 2',
  },

]

const ctx8 = document.getElementById("tsa-applications-trending");
const chart8 = new Chart(ctx8, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4'],
    datasets: app_data_trend
  },
  options: trend_options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:80vh; width:80vw">
  <canvas id="tsa-applications-trending"></canvas>
</div>
```